# Pundit: how to handle multiple error codes for one unauthorized action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I use pundit to handle my API policies, I have an item show that can be forbidden to user in some cases, and in other cases just restricted. By restricted I mean it's forbidden now, but if he pays he could access it then. So I need my API to respond with a specific code (`402 Payment Required`) so the client can invite the user to pay in order to unlock the show.

This is my current code, it only respond with `403` when pundit returns false.

Where would it be best to implement a condition to return `403` OR `402` in order to be DRY and clean?

```
class Api::V1::ItemController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    authorize @item
  end
end

class ItemPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def show?
    return true if record.public?

    # 403 will be generated, that's ok.
    return false if !record.band.members.include?(user)

    # If that condition is false I want to generate a 402 error at the end, not a 403.
    user.premium?
  end
end

class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
  include Pundit

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def user_not_authorized(_exception)
    # Here I've got the exception with :policy, :record and :query, 
    # also I can access :current_user so I could go for a condition, 
    # but that would include duplicated code from  ItemPolicy#show?.
    render json: { error: { message: "Access denied" } }, status: :forbidden
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Pundit` cannot handle different error types out of the box. And it is built to always expect the policy's methods to return `true` or false `false`. Therefore, raising another custom error and rescuing from that in the controller will not work, because it would break view methods too.

I suggest a workaround to introduce different error types. Something like this might work:

```
# in the policy
class ItemPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def show?
    return true if record.public?
    return false unless record.band.members.include?(user)

    if user.premium?
      true
    else
      Current.specific_response_error_code = :payment_required
      false
    end
  end
end

# in the controller
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
  include Pundit

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def user_not_authorized(_exception)
    case Current.specific_response_error_code
    when :payment_required
      render json: { error: { message: "Premium required" } }, status: :payment_required
    else
      render json: { error: { message: "Access denied" } }, status: :forbidden
    end
  end
end
```

I would not consider using the global `CurrentAttributes` a good practice, but they are part of Rails and in this case, using this global data store avoids overriding pundit internals.

You might want to read the API docs about [`CurrentAttributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html).

Comment: I like it ! I'll wait a bit to see if there is other options before acception your answer. Thank you !

Comment: Well there's an issue now when I use `ItemPolicy#show?` for anything else than `authorize` as it raises an error. It means I can't use view helpers for example : `policy(@item).show?` still needs to return a boolean.

Comment: @adesurirey I get your point. After looking into the pundit source code I am thinking about a workaround. What version of Ruby on Rails do you use?

Comment: I use rails 5.2.2.1

Comment: @adesurirey I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann ! Didn't know about `CurrentAttributes`. Makes me think we could do the same with a readable instance variable `@specific_response_error_code`. Would you say it's better to use `CurrentAttributes`?

Answer (score -1):

**create Response module in app/controllers/concerns/response.rb**

```
module Response
  def json_response(object, status = :ok)
    render json: object, status: status
  end
end
```

**create ExceptionHandler in app/controllers/concerns/exception_handler.rb**

```
module ExceptionHandler
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :unauthorized_request
  end

  private

  # JSON response with message; Status code 401 - Unauthorized
  def unauthorized_request(e)
    json_response({ message: e.message }, :unauthorized)
  end
end
```

**in app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
   include Response
   include ExceptionHandler
end
```

**THAT'S IT**

Comment: That always returns the same 401 status code